# Sticky footer issues - How do I get content height 100% minus Header and Footer

Tags: footer, sticky, css

I have written this sticky footer template and I want my content div to have a 100% min-height. Problem is, when I do that, it extends under the footer, with an extra height of header height + footer height. How can I fix this? It should support also short content and long content, in the same manner of the sticky footer. Do I need to use jQuery? I'm a beginner so please KISS.

HTML

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="content">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#form1 {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
   min-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
.header {
   background:#990066;
   height:100px;
}
.content {
   background:#ffffcc;
   padding-bottom:100px;   /* Height of the footer */
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 1120px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#333;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with just css.

HTML (note the slight change in nesting for the footer div)

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

---

CSS

```
html, body, #form1 {height: 100%;}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
    padding-bottom: 150px; /* must be same height as the footer */
}  

.footer {
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
}
```

---

Adapted from here.

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Also a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zf8Fh/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
.content {
    min-height: calc(100% - 100px - 100px);   /* minus header-height minus footer-height */
}
```

Minimum height of the content element is set to 100% minus 100px (height of the header) and 100px (height of the footer). Using CSS function `calc()`, the browser calculates the exact height. This would be better in terms of cross browser compatibility:

```
.content {
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px - 100px);
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px - 100px);
    min-height: calc(100% - 100px - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some words to explain your answer to the OP?

Comment: Actually, due to some problems in Opera (empty space at the bottom) I recommend using a short jQuery snippet to calculate the height of the content element. You can find it here (http://nicholasbarger.com/2011/08/04/jquery-makes-100-height-so-much-easier/) This is a more reliable solution and you don't have to worry about browser compatibility issues :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fixed postion of .footer class in css like below

```
.footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;   /* Height of the footer */
  background:#333;
}
```

Comment: I don't want a fixed footer. When there is little content, it has to stick to the bottom. When there is long content, I want the footer to naturally go down at the end of content.
The footer is not my issue. I want the same with the content div:
When there is little content, I want the content div to stretch until to the footer. When there is much content, I want the content div to naturally stretch to contain all content.

Comment: I think its not possible without using js so You should add some js to add height in content div according to height of page.